# How to sync ng-model data after $(input).val('') to $scope

Tags: jquery, angularjs

For example,

Then I reset the input value via jQuery like:
$('#example').val('');
But the value of angular model "Something" won't change.
How to solve this trouble pleases!!!

Comment: `<input id="example" ng-model="Something">`

Comment: You need to stop using jQuery, Angular can't "see" the value change if you use jQuery.  You probably want to add a method to update it to the $scope object in your controller or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Angular, then do it in Angular way.

I believe you shouldn't use jQuery to bind AngularJS scope variable. On input element you must use `ng-model` directive that will take care about angular two way binding.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <input id="sampleInput" ng-model="testInput"/> 
  Below you can get updated value of scope variable.
  {{testInput}}
  <button ng-click="click()"></button>
</div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('mainCtrl', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.click = function(){
      console.log($scope.testInput); //here is updated scope variable inside controller 
   };
}]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is if I call `$scope.someInfo = some_json;`,the $scope value will change but the DOM doesn't. How shold I do if I want to change the $scope value and DOM value at the same time. Thanks very much;)

Comment: @user2981324 have you bind someInfo on UI using `ng-model` or `ng-bind`..Can you please upload your code. So that the things will be clear

Comment: HTML  `<input ng-model="apple" ng-repeat="apple in apples" value="{{apple}}> <button ng-click="reset()"></button>` JS `var apples_json; var default_apples_json; $scope.reset = function($scope){ $scope.apples = default_apples_json; }` Just like this. After I change values in input , if I want to reset all these values I click the button. But in console I saw the $scope.apples change but the inputs doesn't.

Comment: @user2981324 try this code HTML : `<input ng-model="apple" ng-repeat="apple in apples"> <button ng-click="reset()"></button>` JS: `var copyOfApples = angular.copy($scope.apples); $scope.reset=function(){ $scope.apples=angular.copy(copyOfApples);}` Use shouldn't use the direct reference..if you do that then the actual copy of object will change..use object cloning. In angular you can use `angular.copy` like we did 'clone()' in jquery. Thanks

Comment: I'm very appreciated.

Comment: I'm on way home, I 'll check it immediately when arrived:)Thank you again, I have too much to learn.

Comment: Oh,sorry.It seems doesn't work.The copyofApple will change with the DOM just as $scope.apples does....So I cannoto reset it to the defalut values.

Comment: $scope.apples=angular.copy(copyOfApples); Maybe you mean  $scope.apples=copyOfApples; .But in this case ,the $scope.apples does change, but the DOM doesn't. I'm so confused...

Comment: No...when you get apples object at that time you should set `$scope.apples = apples_obj; var copyOfApple = angular.copy($scope.apples); // making copy to use it inside reset`
Then inside your reset function use $scope.apples = angular.copy(copyOfApples)

Comment: Finally,it solved. I tried to reorganized the order or these variables and the angular.copy works. After all,thank you very much~~~